# What is the grammar behind “qui plus est féminine”?

Tags: grammaire, sens

> Le thème de l'homosexualité, qui plus est féminine, est assez rarement traité en bande dessinée.

I can’t decipher whether it’s saying “which isn’t feminine anymore” or “which is more feminine” or something else entirely.

I’m guessing it’s not the first one because since it’s an article it would have “ne” with the “plus”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une expression figée (*set*) qui est une locution adverbiale ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_plus_est)) servant à [renchérir](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rench%C3%A9rir) sur ce qui est affirmé ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plus)) ; c'est synonyme de *de plus/en plus* ([Wiktionnaire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui_plus_est) : *what's more,  moreover, besides* ; [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/plus/61113#663049) : *what's, what is more*.). Il est inutile de trop analyser une expression figée, qui ici sert d'élément incident de la phase (« une espèce de parenthèse », LBU § 377) mais on peut y voir *qui* comme une « pronom neutre ayant comme antécédent la phrase elle-même ou une partie de celle-ci » (LBU14 § 713 b). Dans le contexte de la phrase de la question, ça se rapproche de « et encore plus celle (l'homosexualité) des femmes » (d'où le fait qu'on trouve l'accord en genre de l'adjectif *féminine*  avec *homosexualité*, nom féminin) ; on en comprend que le thème de l'homosexualité est assez rarement traité en bande dessinée et encore moins quand il s'agit de l'homosexualité chez les femmes.